# Intel MIC offloading -- how does it work with STL?

Tags: c++, stl, eigen, icc, intel-mic

I'm working with a [system](http://www.idiap.ch/~cdubout/code/ffld.tar.gz) that's implemented in C++/OpenMP code, and it uses STL and [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)'s data structures all over the place. Algorithmically, the code seems like a great candidate for acceleration with the new Intel MIC ([Xeon Phi](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-developers-quick-start-guide)) cards.

A typical parallel loop in the code looks like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        computeIntensiveFunction(some_STL_or_eigen_container[i]);
```

The above pseudocode runs with reasonable performance, but it'd be great to offload some of it to the Xeon Phi card. Here's my attempt at doing this:

```
#pragma offload target (mic)    // <---- NEW
#pragma omp parallel for private(i)
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        computeIntensiveFunction(some_STL_or_eigen_container[i]);
```

However, the Intel ICC/ICPC compiler spits out an error like this: `error: function "computeIntensiveFunction" called in offload region must have been declared with compatible "target" attribute.` It seems that complaints like this appear for functions and data structures that involve STL or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

---

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

I'm new to using Xeon Phi (recovering CUDA programmer), so I don't entirely understand the boundaries for "what can be offloaded?"

Comment: Hmm, it seems like the flag `-offload-attribute-target=mic` might be part of the solution here.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like:

```
void __attribute__((target(mic))) computeIntensiveFunction(std::vector<sometype> myvar);
```

defined in your source. This defines the function on the MIC side of things so that it can be called from an offload region.

Comment: So that the function gets defined on the mic side of things. Without it you have a function call to an undefined function.

Comment: Cool, that's something that should be part of your answer.